# R: Subset rows from dataframe based on range of given time

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, subset

Assume I have df1:

```
Start_Date    End_Date     Value
2001-01-01    2001-12-31   1
2002-01-01    2002-12-31   2
2003-01-01    2003-12-31   3
2004-01-01    2004-12-31   4
2005-01-01    2005-12-31   5
```

& df2:

```
DateTime
2003-01-01
2003-05-09
2004-12-31
2005-01-31
2005-08-13
```

What I would like to do is to import Value from df1 into df2 by checking which DateTime in df2 falls in between Start_Date & End_Date in df1. A view of desired outcome:

```
DateTime      Value
2003-01-01    3
2003-05-09    3
2004-12-31    4
2005-01-31    5
2005-08-13    5
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` gives a solution.

Before we start make sure all dates are formatted in the same way:

```r
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Start_Date=ymd(Start_Date), End_Date=dmy(End_Date))

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(DateTime=ymd(DateTime))
```

In your case it's only necessary for your column `End_Date`.

First I crossjoin both data.frames since I don't see any easy solution for combining both dfs.

```r
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)
```

Next using `filter` and `between`

```r
df3 %>% 
  filter(between(DateTime, Start_Date, End_Date)) %>%
  select(-c(Start_Date, End_Date))
```

gives

```r
  Value   DateTime
1     3 2003-01-01
2     3 2003-05-09
3     4 2004-12-31
4     5 2005-01-31
5     5 2005-08-13
```

#### Another option using package `data.table`

```r
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, on = .(Start_Date <= DateTime, End_Date >= DateTime), 
    .(DateTime, Value)]
```

yields

```r
     DateTime Value
1: 2003-01-01     3
2: 2003-05-09     3
3: 2004-12-31     4
4: 2005-01-31     5
5: 2005-08-13     5
```

Answer (score 1):

additional option. Using `lubridate` you can check in what interval the date is

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(out = df1$Value[(DateTime %within% interval(df1$Start_Date, df1$End_Date))])
```